# Really simple question about reference of list in python

Tags: python, list, reference

I have a really simple question about references in python.

I assume you are familiar with this:

```
aa = [1,2]
bb = aa
aa[0] = 100
print(bb)
```

As you might guess, the output will be

```
[100, 2]
```

and it's totally OK ✔

Let's do another example:

```
l = [[],[],[]]
a = l[0]
l[0] = [1,2]
print(a)
```

But here the output is:

```
[]
```

I know why that happened.

It's because, on line 3, we made an entirely different list and "replaced it"(not changing but replacing) with `l[0]`

Now my question is "Can I somehow replace `l[0]` with `[1,2]` and also keep `a` as a reference?

P.S not like `l[0].append(1,2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Not really, but there might be something close enough.

---

The problem is, under the covers, `a` is a pointer-to-a-list, and `l` is a pointer-to-a-list-of-pointers-to-lists. When you `a = l[0]`, what that actually translates to at the CPU is "dereference the pointer `l`, treat the resulting region of memory as a list object, get the first object (which will be the address of another list), and set the value of pointer `a` to that address". Once you've done that, `a` and `l[0]` are only related by concidence; the are two separate pointers that happen, for the moment, to point at the same object. If you assign to either variable, you're changing the value of a pointer, not the contents of the pointed-to object.

Broadly speaking, there's a few ways the computer could practically do what you ask.

1. Modify the pointed-to object (list) without modifying either pointer. That's what the `append` function does, along with the many other mutators of python lists. If you want to do this in a way that perhaps more clearly expresses your intent, you could do `l[0][:] = [1,2]`. That's a list copy operation, copying into the object pointed to by both `l[0]` and `a`. This is your best bet as a developer, though note that copy operations are O(n).
2. Implement `a` as a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-list that is automatically dereferenced (to merely a pointer-to-list) when accessed. This is not, AFAIK, something Python provides any support for; almost no language does. In C you could say `list ** a = &(l[0]);` but then any time you want to actually do anything with `a` you'd have to use `*a` instead.
3. Tell the interpreter to observe that `a` is an alias to `l[0]`, rather than its own, separate variable. As far as I know, Python doesn't support this either. In C, you could do it as `#define a (l[0])` though you'd want to `#undef a` when it went out of scope.
4. Rather than making `a` a list variable (which is implemented as a pointer-to-list), make it a function: `a = lambda: l[0]`. This means you have to use `a()` instead of `a` anywhere you want to get the actual content of `l[0]`, and you can't assign to `l[0]` through `a()` (or through `a` directly). But it does work, in Python. You could even go so far as to use properties, which would let you skip the parentheses and assign through `a`, but at the cost of writing a bunch more code to wrap the lists (I'm not aware of a way to attach properties to lists directly, though one might exist, so you'd instead have to create a new object wrapping the list).

Answer (score 1):

If a = l then calling a[0] in that case would yield [1,2], however, you are deleting the list that “a” was referencing, therefore the reference is destroyed as well. You need to either make a = l and call a[0] or reset the reference by calling a = l[0] again.

Comment: Your first sentence is confusing and a bit off.   you might want to just remove that line in your response.

Answer (score 0):

The original array at l[0] and the [1,2] array are two different objects.  there is no way to do that short of re-assigning the a variable to l[0] again once the change has been made.